# Possible to change class tag name on Emmet autocomplete?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet, react-css-modules

Our team uses CSS-Modules, so instead of using "className" (in React), we use "styleName". Is there a way to change Emmet in VScode to autocomplete to "styleName" instead of "className"?

My current preferences:

```
{
    "emmet.includeLanguages": { "javascript": "javascriptreact" },
    "emmet.syntaxProfiles": { "javascript": "jsx" },
    "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
    "emmet.preferences": { "jsx.classAttributeName": "styleName" },
    "cssModules.camelCase": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in vscode preferences by adding:

```
"emmet.preferences": { "jsx.classAttributeName": "styleName" }
```

Comment: That seems like it should work but it's unfortunately not. I'll add my current preferences to see if I'm missing anything. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @SQ did you resolve this issue? it is not working for me either though I am using tsx

Comment: sorry for the delay @killer_manatee -- no, I never was able to get this working :-\